# php: how to get each value from the array

Tags: php, codeigniter

i getting   array value the below code

```
$userdays_template=$this->templateroutinemodel->get_AllDays_by_templateRoutine_id($rid);
```

And i printed( `echo("---userdays_template--.var_dump($userdays_template));`) it and 
it gave me output like:  `array(4) { [0]=> string(3) "965" [1]=> string(3) "964" [2]=> string(3) "959" [3]=> string(3) "958" }`

So **my question is ,how can i get each value from this array in a loop?...**

What i tried:

```
  $userdays_template=$this->templateroutinemodel->get_AllDays_by_templateRoutine_id($rid); 
    echo("---userdays_template---------".var_dump($userdays_template));
      if (is_array($userdays_template)) 
          {
          foreach ($userdays_template as $row) 
              {   
               $day_value= $row->day_id;;
                echo("---day---------".$day_value);//not printing the this line,why? 
             } 
         }
```

but its not printing this echo(`echo("---day---------".$day_value);`). please help me

Comment: Looks like you have an array, not an object. Try `$day_value = $row;`

Comment: @billyonecan Thanks your answer helped. Its working fine.  Just answer your comment in a Answer form, so that i can accept your answer, --majority goes to u , becoz u have answered first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your below code:

```
$day_value= $row->day_id;
```

With the following code:

```
$day_value= $row;
echo $day_value;
```

You have two semicolumn that give the error. And also there is no day_id in the array remove that. Use the above code.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like all you need to do is:

```
foreach ($userdays_template as $row) 
{   
     echo("---day---------".$row);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

replace your code with this :-

```
$userdays_template=$this->templateroutinemodel->get_AllDays_by_templateRoutine_id($rid); 
if (is_array($userdays_template)) 
   {
     foreach ($userdays_template as $row) 
        {   
         echo("---day---------".$row);
        } 
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the foreach as associative array so you can do what you need in two ways
the first:

```
     foreach ($userdays_template as $key=>$val) 
     {   
           $day_value= $val;
           echo("---day---------".$day_value);
     }
```

OR use the for loop and use the array index 0,1,2,...

```
    for ($i = 0 ; $i < count($userdays_template))  
    {
      echo("---day---------".$userdays_template[$i]);
    }
```